# window.location.replace(document.URL) not triggering if url contains '#?' at the end

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

In my sample website, I was trying to redirect my page using javascript `window.location.replace` method. As I need to refresh the page, I used `document.URL`. It works well. But sometimes I noticed that it not working without giving any error. Finally I found that some links adds `#` in address bar and one of my javascript add a `?` to the same. At that time the code `window.location.replace(document.URL)` wont execute. Is that due to the characters in the URL?

here is my function(sample)

```
function sample() {
alert(document.URL);
window.location.replace(document.URL);
}
```

the alert showing url like `http://localhost/something/#?`. and at this time it will not refresh the page.

Comment: Your function doesn't even have `window.location.replace()`. Why not use `window.location.reload()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any of these 
`location.reload(); 
window.location.reload();
 window.location.href=window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `location.reload();` instead.